# DataGridView has DataSource but RowCount property = 0 in UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource

I have created a calendar which works on a form, but when the code is transferred to a `usercontrol`, one of the `datagridview` controls does not populate. The `datasource` appears to be correct when looking at the properties during debugging but the `rowcount` is 0 after setting the `datasource`.

```
    private void populateTimeGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    for (int x = 0; x < times.Length; x++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(x.ToString(), typeof(bool))
        }
    dt.LoadDataRow(times, true);
    timeGrid.RowTemplate.MinimumHeight = timeGrid.Height;
    timeGrid.DataSource = dt;
}
```

"times" is simply a string array of length 40 with all values set to null.
Just want to specify that this code works on a form, but doesn't work on a `usercontrol`.

Comment: @ASh sorry i forgot to type that in when copying over my code. This isn't the error as the code runs perfectly fine, which i do not believe missing increment would allow. Also the datasource (dt) has the correct values inside it just doesn't seem to add to the datagridview (timeGrid)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to bind data source to the gridview.

timeGrid.DataSource = dt;
timeGrid.Databind();

Comment: Is this not for Web UI? I am using a windows form and this method doesn't appear to be present.